# Visual Studio C function syntax error

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, c99, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to implement a C function like this in Visual Studio, I've followed [Creating a C Project in Visual Studio](http://winquire.org/2013/02/03/creating-a-c-project-in-visual-studio/)

```
void changeParameters(int &a, int n) {
   for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      printf("some text goes here");
   }
}
```

However, I receive the following errors

1. syntax error &
2. undeclared identifier i

I've tried both VS 2008 and 2010, but the same errors

Is this C99 features? I remember I can compile this kind of code in Visual Studio C++ 6.0

Comment: You *probably* want to change `int &a` to `int *a` (which means updating any references to `a` in the body of the function), but since you never use `a` it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: @Thanks everyone for the prompt reply. I force the file to compile as C++ and it is OK now

Comment: How did you force it compile as C++? It should be treated as C++ automatically if you name it with a `.cpp` suffix. If you keep the name as `blah.c` but force it to compile as C++, you're asking for trouble down the road.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry for using the wrong word, I want to emphasize that this kind of code should be compiled with C++ compiler. Setting **Default** in VS will cause it to select C or C++ compiler depending on the file extension

Comment: You should use Visual Studio 2013 to get support for for-loops initial declaration in C, if there is no particular reason for you to use an older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
```

The `i` declaration in the `for` loop is a c99 feature, c89 does not support it. It is also supported in C++.

In C also references are not supported (neither in c89 / c99 / c11):

```
void changeParameters(int &a, int n)
```

this function declaration is not valid because of `int &a` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

C has no references. This function declaration

```
void changeParameters(int &a, int n);
```

defined the first parameter as a reference to int. You can try to change the function declaration as

```
void changeParameters(int *a, int n);
```

Take into account that MS VS 2010 does not support even `C99` not speaking about the most recent C Standard.